# Android 9 drawable in Button not showing

Tags: java, android, android-drawable, android-9.0-pie

I put a drawable in a button, that works on Android 6 but not on Android 9 devices.

Same code, no exceptions, it’s just does not shows up. First I scale my drawable to fit in my button and change the color of the drawable, here is my code:

> Integer scaleWidth = myButton.getWidth(); Integer scaleHeight
>   =myButton.getHeight();
>
> Drawable drawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.myDrawable);
>
> Drawable wrappedDrawable = DrawableCompat.wrap(drawable);
>                   DrawableCompat.setTint(wrappedDrawable, iColor);
>
> wrappedDrawable.setBounds(0, 0, (int)
>   (wrappedDrawable.getIntrinsicWidth() * 0.5), (int)
>   (wrappedDrawable.getIntrinsicHeight() * 0.5));
>                   ScaleDrawable sd = new ScaleDrawable(wrappedDrawable, 0, scaleWidth, scaleHeight);
>
> myButton.setCompoundDrawables(null, null, sd.getDrawable(), null);

EDIT:

this works:

```
Drawable drawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.xxx);
                    Drawable wrappedDrawable = DrawableCompat.wrap(drawable);
                    DrawableCompat.setTint(wrappedDrawable, iColor);

                    wrappedDrawable.setBounds(0, 0, (int) (wrappedDrawable.getIntrinsicWidth() * 0.5), (int) (wrappedDrawable.getIntrinsicHeight() * 0.5));
```

Answer (score 2):

Do you really need to add the button drawable programmatically? Why not try my implementation which is to set the drawables in xml file? **This code is already tested in Android 7.0 up until to Android 10.0.** Here is my code:

```
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_tax_receipt"
                style="@style/page_button"
                android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_receipt_light"
                android:text="@string/title_activity_tax_receipt"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="27dp"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="225dp" />
```

You can change the color of the drawable by changing the color value of **android:drawableTint**

OR use this easier approach:

[image]

Comment: you are right, your solution would work for me but I already found a solution, just edit my question, thanks anyway :)